# ReportViewer.PrintDialog() throws exception when printing to Adobe PDF

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, reporting-services

I am working on a WinForms app that uses the `ReportViewer` control to show a few Reporting Services reports.  On these screens, we allow the user to print the report by calling the `PrintDialog()` method on the ReportViewer like so:

```
_reportViewer.PrintDialog();
```

This works fine in most cases, it brings up the standard windows print dialog, the user chooses what printer they want to print to, and it prints.  However, when the user chooses to print to PDF using "Adobe PDF", it throws a `Win32Exception: The specified datatype is invalid`.  The file dialog to choose where to save the pdf doesn't even come up.

This only happens with Adobe PDF printer.  I installed [NitroPDF](http://www.nitropdf.com/) and used their PDF printer and it works without a problem.

Does anybody have an idea on what could be causing this to happen?

**Edit:**

Here is the stack trace:

```
at System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.PrintControllerWithStatusDialog.OnStartPrint(PrintDocument document, PrintEventArgs e)
at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document)
at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.PrintDialog(PrinterSettings printerSettings)
at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer.PrintDialog()
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you try to print to Adobe PDF from Notepad or some other program?

Comment: No, I can print fine from notepad, word etc...

Comment: If you can print to other printers including NitroPDF, I would suspect the problem is with your Adobe Acrobat. However, you also said that you can print to AdobePDF from other sources like notepad...can you try printing to AdobePDF from something more complex like a web page? Also, can you successfully export the report to PDF? And is your report local or remote?

Comment: I can successfully print this web page to AdobePDF.  By exporting, do you mean through the report viewer?  Exporting to PDF through the report viewer works without a problem.  The reports are local.

Comment: Hm, try setting the AdobePDF print engine as the default printer. Do you get the same results? Also, take a look at http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/822/cpsid_82252.html

Comment: Could you post a stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: The error still occurs when the default printer is set to AdobePDF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't truly fix the problem but solves it in the users' eyes.

Trap the error thrown by the PDF Printer then invoke the Export to PDF functionality built into Reporting Services.  It doesn't error in Winforms even when printing to the PDF Printer does.  From the user perspective they "printed to pdf" like normal and the experience is identical. It's a work around that works.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the ReportViewer control just renders each page as a bitmap image. So when printing to PDF, if the resolution is high, it could be a huge bitmap. Maybe AdobePDF has problems with large bitmaps, Adobe have so many other bugs! Try lowering the resolution as a test?

I have an application that uses the ReportServer API to get the page bitmaps and chunks them into parts to be handled by a custom print processor

Comment: I tried lowering the resolution to 72 dots per inch (the lowest resolution possible) and the error still occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the contents of the report are creating this problem. I mean to say that the report may contain certain characters that Adobe PDF printer is not able to recognize.

Can you try to print a very simple/basic/blank report and see if that works.

Comment: I just tried it with a blank report and it still errors.  This is happening for all of our reports as well.

Comment: related note - I am getting a similar issue with some users that print to a specific laser printer.  NO issues with any other printers.